# Why isn't the second selection disabled when i pick all products in the first one?

Tags: javascript, html

https://jsfiddle.net/a8r057du/

I don't understand why I don't disable the select "A" when I select the all products option

```
<form method="post" action="shop.php">

<select name='filterp'>
    <option defaultSelected>Please select an option</option>
    <option  value="allp" isSelect="disabled()">All Products</option>
    <option  value="milan">Products Milan</option>
    <option value="juve" >Products Juventus</option>
</select>

<script>
      function disabled()
      {
          document.getElementsById("A").disabled=false;   
      }
     
  </script>

<select name="A" id="A">
    <option defaultSelected>Please select an option</option>
    <option id="mesh" value="mesh">mesh</option>
    <option  id="shorts" value="shorts">shorts</option>
    <option id="socks" value="socks">socks</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Filter" id="filtrogo" >
```

Comment: You've invented your own `isSelect` "event". It doesn't do anything. Instead, you should listen `change` event on the select element, and check, if that particular option is selected. Notice also, tha `disabled` should be `true` when you want to disable a control element.

Comment: what  is `isSelect` ?, its not an actual method

Answer (score 2):

you have `isSelect="disabled()"` in your code which doesnt do anything because its not an actual method

to disable the select if the option is selected, you need to use `onchange` or the `change` eventListener and check if the option you clicked is the "all products" option

js code :

```js
function change(value){
    if(value === "allp"){
     document.getElementById("A").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

here, i used an if statement to check if the value is "allp" which is the "all products" option and disable the `select` element

another problem is you have`document.getElementById("A").disabled = false;` , it should be `true`

full code:

```html
<form method="post" action="shop.php">
    
    <select name='filterp' onchange="selectOnchange(value)">
        <option defaultSelected>Please select an option</option>
        <option  value="allp">All Products</option>
        <option  value="milan">Products Milan</option>
        <option value="juve" >Products Juventus</option>
    </select>
    
    <script>
         function selectOnchange(value){
    if(value === "allp"){
     document.getElementById("A").disabled= true;
    }
    }
      </script>
    
    <select name="A" id="A">
        <option defaultSelected>Please select an option</option>
        <option id="mesh" value="mesh">mesh</option>
        <option  id="shorts" value="shorts">shorts</option>
        <option id="socks" value="socks">socks</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" id="filtrogo" >
</form>
```

and you also used `document.getElementsById` which is wrong, it should be `getElementById`

Comment: @MattiaSchipilliti lemme know if you have any doubts

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much you saved me

```html
<form method="post" action="shop.php">
    
    <select name='filterp' onchange="selectOnchange(value)">
        <option defaultSelected>Please select an option</option>
        <option  value="allp">All Products</option>
        <option  value="milan">Products Milan</option>
        <option value="juve" >Products Juventus</option>
    </select>
    
    <script>
         function selectOnchange(value){
    if(value === "allp"){
     document.getElementById("A").disabled= true;
    }
    }
      </script>
    
    <select name="A" id="A">
        <option defaultSelected>Please select an option</option>
        <option id="mesh" value="mesh">mesh</option>
        <option  id="shorts" value="shorts">shorts</option>
        <option id="socks" value="socks">socks</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" id="filtrogo" >
</form>
```

Comment: btw you can accept my answer by clicking the tick if this helped you :D